# How to delete Volume Shadow Copies using C#?

Tags: c#, volume-shadow-service

I need to delete one or all shadow copies in Windows Server 2003. How I can do it using C#?
For example, I can write "vssadmin delete shadows /all" in cmd and all will be fine, but me need to do it automatically.

Comment: `new Process("vssadmin delete shadows /all").Start()`. Just google "c# process"

Comment: It's not working. If it was that easy, I would not ask. For do it need to use some API.

Comment: Above code should work. Why do you need to delete \*all\* shadow copies?

Comment: I need to automate the whole process of creating and deleting copies, and doing it every day. And the code still does not work (because this operation needs to be confirmed, and automatic confirmation doesn't work, so for it need an some API)

Answer (score 0):

Add "/quiet" to the end of your vssadmin command. This will suppress the user prompt and allow you to delete shadow copies with C#:

Ex. vssadmin delete shadows /all /quiet

You can also specify a particular shadow copy:

Ex. vssadmin delete shadows /Shadow={b2708a51-9bdc-4db0-b80a-008ba8e4689f} /quiet